# The current description of ai-design might be too restrictive

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the description of the tag [ai-design](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-design) is

> For questions related to successful or novel designing standards and procedures of Artificially Intelligent agents.

However, there are questions on this website that look like "How should I design the architecture of a neural network to achieve X?". I believe that this type of questions should fall under the tag [ai-design](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-design) or is there an another tag for this type of questions? If not, I suggest to change the description of the tag [ai-design](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-design) to make it more broadly applicable.

Comment: I'm going to think on this one.  Definitely that description could use a revamp!

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following new description to make this tag more broadly applicable

> For questions related to designing standards and procedures of intelligent agents, algorithms or models.